# When I move a body part the mirrored body part moves too

Tags: rigging, mirror

I added rigs to my body and, when I move the arm, the other one moves too, but the other one's bones stay in the same way. What can I do?

Comment: please don't use all caps. read number 6 on this page: https://www.skillsyouneed.com/write/capital-letters.html#:~:text=Overusing%20Capitals%20is%20Rude,IS%20SHOUTING%2C%20and%20it's%20rude.&text=But%20in%20email%20etiquette%2C%20online,want%20to%20shout%20at%20someone.

Comment: oh i used it so it can get more attention

Comment: Please take the [tour](https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour) and read [how to ask a good question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). You can get more attention by improving the body of your question with proper punctuation and great description. (Maybe *"the other one bones stay in the same way"* could use a better formulation.)

Answer (score -1):

it will happen , because mirror objects should move just like the real life